# Html теги после implode

Tags: laravel, blade

есть код

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
        $test1[$key] = "<a href='" . $value->slug . "'>" . $value->title . '</a>';
    }
    $result->category_id_title = implode(', ', $test1);
```

мне выводит

```
<a href='kategoriya-0'>Категория #0</a>, <a href='kategoriya-4'>Категория #4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался -  в шаблоне нужно было вставить:

```
{!! html_entity_decode($result->category_id_title) !!}
```